# How to stop 'import psycopg2' from causing an Exception when starting an Azure Container?

Tags: postgresql, azure, psycopg2

I am trying to deploy a Django REST API using Azure App Service on Linux. I am using a postgresql Database and deploy via pipeline. Azure has postgresql 9.6. After running my pipeline, the Website shows an *Server Error (500)*.
The AppLogs show, that the Container couldn't be started due an failed import of `psycopg2`.

```
[ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/home/site/wwwroot/antenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 25, in 
     import psycopg2 as Database
   File "/home/site/wwwroot/antenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 50, in 
     from psycopg2._psycopg import (                     # noqa
ImportError: /home/site/wwwroot/antenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: PQencryptPasswordConn
```

In the Build-stage of my pipeline, I set up my environment (python3.7) like this:

```
- script: |
    python -m venv antenv
    source antenv/bin/activate
    python -m pip install --upgrade pip
    pip install setup
    pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Where requirements.txt looks like this:

```
Django==3.0.2
djangorestframework==3.11.0
psycopg2-binary==2.8.4
pandas==0.25.3
pytest==5.3.5
pytest-django==3.8.0
pytest-mock==2.0.0
python-dateutil==2.8.1
sqlparse==0.3.0
whitenoise==5.0.1
```

BuildJob and DeploymentJob seem to run flawless. the Build-logs indicate that `psycopg2_binary-2.8.4-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl` was correctly downloaded and installed.

Also the App runs fine on my machine when using the database on azure by configuring in the settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'databasename',
        'USER': 'user@postgresqlserver',
        'PASSWORD': 'Password',
        'HOST': 'postgresqlserver.postgres.database.azure.com',
        'PORT': '',
        'OPTIONS': {'sslmode': 'require'}
    }
}  # Of course the info is actually saved in environment variables
```

This gives me the feeling, that something with the *psycopg2* installation is not working... For others the *psycopg2-**binary** seemed to do the trick but unfortunateley not for me.

Am I right to assume that on azure I'm nether able to install postgresql10 as suggested here https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/983 nor can install from source like suggested here https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/1018?

There must be something I am missing, I would be grateful for any advice!

EDIT:
Taking a look at the library (as suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/a/59652816/13183775) I found that I don't have a *PQencryptPasswordConn* function but only a *PQencryptPassword* function. I have the feeling that this is expected for Postgresql9.6 (https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/blob/cb3353be1f10590cdc2a894ada42c3b4c171feb7/psycopg/psycopgmodule.c#L466).
To check, whether there are multiple versions *libpq*:

```
/>find . -name "libpq*"
./var/lib/dpkg/info/libpq5:amd64.symbols
./var/lib/dpkg/info/libpq5:amd64.shlibs
./var/lib/dpkg/info/libpq5:amd64.list
./var/lib/dpkg/info/libpq5:amd64.triggers
./var/lib/dpkg/info/libpq-dev.list
./var/lib/dpkg/info/libpq5:amd64.md5sums
./var/lib/dpkg/info/libpq-dev.md5sums
./usr/share/doc/libpq5
./usr/share/doc/libpq-dev
./usr/share/locale/ko/LC_MESSAGES/libpq5-9.6.mo
./usr/share/locale/it/LC_MESSAGES/libpq5-9.6.mo
./usr/share/locale/pl/LC_MESSAGES/libpq5-9.6.mo
./usr/share/locale/zh_TW/LC_MESSAGES/libpq5-9.6.mo
./usr/share/locale/tr/LC_MESSAGES/libpq5-9.6.mo
./usr/share/locale/cs/LC_MESSAGES/libpq5-9.6.mo
./usr/share/locale/de/LC_MESSAGES/libpq5-9.6.mo
./usr/share/locale/ru/LC_MESSAGES/libpq5-9.6.mo
./usr/share/locale/sv/LC_MESSAGES/libpq5-9.6.mo
./usr/share/locale/pt_BR/LC_MESSAGES/libpq5-9.6.mo
./usr/share/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/libpq5-9.6.mo
./usr/share/locale/es/LC_MESSAGES/libpq5-9.6.mo
./usr/share/locale/zh_CN/LC_MESSAGES/libpq5-9.6.mo
./usr/share/locale/ja/LC_MESSAGES/libpq5-9.6.mo
./usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/libpq.pc
./usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5
./usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so
./usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5.9
./usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.a
./usr/include/postgresql/libpq-events.h
./usr/include/postgresql/libpq-fe.h
./usr/include/postgresql/libpq
./usr/include/postgresql/libpq/libpq-fs.h
./usr/include/postgresql/internal/libpq
./usr/include/postgresql/internal/libpq-int.h>
```

Sadly I'm not able to see here wether there are multiple libpq versions...

Comment: It looks like the `psycopg2-binary` package is incompatible with your old PostgresQL version; try to install the `psycopg2` package.

Comment: Note from psycopg2 doc: *The binary package is a practical choice for development and testing but in production it is advised to use the package built from sources.*

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! Without any deeper understanding I have been trying this and a view other different variations (psycopg2 and psycopg2-binary both version 2.8.4 and without a specified version) but it didn't seem to make any difference in the end result. Unfortunateley I wasn't able to find any information about a specific version known to be working with PostgreSQL9.6...

Comment: I don't have experience with Azure (App Service) but apparently you can open a [shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/how-to-configure-python#open-ssh-session-in-browser) on it. From there I can try to help you further with debugging.

Comment: Yes I can, I would be grateful! Unfortunateley there are some limitations, most notably can't run my virtualenv from there

Comment: Why wouldn't something like `source /path/to/venv/bin/activate` work?

Comment: I can't really find anything about the 'why', and nothing explicitly stating that it is impossible to start a virtualenv. It just doesn't work for me.
The only statement I could find by now about Kudu-terminals in general was _This simple terminal is not for running interactive commands_ from http://blog.amitapple.com/post/45675601255/azurewebsiteterminal/#.XorQM4gzaUk

Comment: @Valecz I was having the same (or very similar) problem as you. What I ended up doing was setting `SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT` to `1` in the the App Service configuration settings. This will [enable build automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-zip?tabs=cli#enable-build-automation-for-zip-deploy). I actually found this in a different article, one on troubleshooting. I'll try to find it.